# Want execute only shell script

Tags: bash

I wrote a shell script to hook into a password protected database. A couple of others want to use the same shell script to share the database access, but I don't want to expose the password that is being used. Is there a way to lock the script so that no one can read it and only execute it? It'd also be ideal for them to enter their sudo password to run the script

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a way to lock the script so that no one can read it and only
>   execute it? It'd also be ideal for them to enter their sudo password
>   to run the script

Sure.  Let's say the script containing the credentials is `/usr/local/bin/myscript`.  Make this file owned by a privileged user.  Let's say we have a user named "credentials":

```
# chown credentials /usr/local/bin/myscript
# chmod 700 /usr/local/bin/myscript
```

Now only the `credentials` user can read and execute this script.

Create another script `/usr/local/bin/mywrapper` that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec sudo -u credentials /usr/local/bin/myscript
```

And create the appropriate `/etc/sudoers` entry:

```
auser   ALL=(credentials) /usr/local/bin/myscript
```

So now, user `auser` runs "mywrapper".  This in turn uses `sudo` to call the real script, which will prompt `auser` for their password.

I think this does everything you want.  We use a mechanism very much like this at my office to protect credentials (in our case, ssh private keys).

Answer (score 0):

In order to execute a shell script, you have to be able to read it. There are a couple of things you could do:

- Who administers this database? Could the users get their own passwords for read only access? That would be ideal because it could limit their access to a small subset of the database.
- If they have to have sudo access to run this script, maybe it's possible to remove the password out of the file and into a file that has 600 permissions set. The problem is that this could leak. For example, what if they run the script with `set -xv`? Then, they could see the password as the script executes.
- Can you create a subset of data they might be interested in outside of the database? Then, have your script access that?

Or, you might want to take a look at several *read-only* modules in Perl. I'm thinking something like [Acme::EyeDrops](http://search.cpan.org/~asavige/Acme-EyeDrops-1.55/lib/Acme/EyeDrops.pm) or [Acme::Bleach](http://search.cpan.org/~dconway/Acme-Bleach-1.13/lib/Acme/Bleach.pm) which remove all those unsightly letters and numbers from your Perl script. (And I wonder why Python programmers say Perl is unreadable?)